# How to make a checkbox in circle shape with custom css?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, angular-material

How do I make a checkbox rounded with custom CSS? Something similar to the image below. I know there are frameworks like bootstrap provides this, but I don't want to use a framework for this sole purpose as I'm already using angular material.

[image]

**HTML Code:**

```
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="notification.checked"> 
    </label>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: refer this link http://www.cssportal.com/blog/style-checkboxes-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You directly use the css from here http://flatlogic.github.io/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/demo/ ..
Just include `.checkbox-circle` class in your code and use.

Comment: Better to link to the page that actually explains it:  http://flatlogic.github.io/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/

Answer (score 6):

If you're sure you want check boxes and not radio buttons

*Check boxes are generally square and several can be checked, radio buttons are circular but only one out of a group can be selected*

I've written a little bit of CSS based off [this](https://paulund.co.uk/style-checkboxes-with-css) (checkboxfour) but I've changed it slightly to make it fit with what you've asked for.

```css
.customcb {
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 2px 0 2px 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.customcb label.inner {
  display: block;
  width: 12.75px;
  height: 12.75px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.125px;
  left: 2.125px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #eee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
.customcb label.outer {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.customcb [type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}
.red.customcb input[type=checkbox]:checked+label.inner {
  background: red
}
.orange.customcb input[type=checkbox]:checked+label.inner {
  background: #d61
}
.green.customcb input[type=checkbox]:checked+label.inner {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="red customcb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="customcb1" name="" />
  <label class="inner" for="customcb1"></label>
  <label class="outer" for="customcb1">Red</label>
</div>

<div class="orange customcb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="customcb2" name="" />
  <label class="inner" for="customcb2"></label>
  <label class="outer" for="customcb2">Amber</label>
</div>

<div class="green customcb">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="customcb3" name="" />
  <label class="inner" for="customcb3"></label>
  <label class="outer" for="customcb3">Green</label>
</div>
```

Also I've shown that you can use different colours by changing the class and of course adding the colour to the CSS, the last 3 sections of CSS are all about the colours. The middle one is the orange from the picture you shared.

If you follow the tutorial I've linked you'll get a good idea of what I've done and why.

I think it might be worth reading [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) which covers all of the input types (feel free to ignore if you know about them already)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

use

```css
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-label::before {
  border-radius: 999px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lucashuang/ew4gc1aL/24/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtiYB.png

Answer (score 1):

Hope This Help You... :-)

```css
/**
     * Checkbox Four
     */
    .checkboxFour {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ddd;
    margin: 20px 90px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    /**
     * Create the checkbox button
     */
    .checkboxFour label {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }

    /**
     * Create the checked state
     */
    .checkboxFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #26ca28;
    }
```

```html
<section>

      <div class="checkboxFour">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFourInput" name="" />
      <label for="checkboxFourInput"></label>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: When you copy/pase an anwser, it's only fair to at least link to the original source: https://paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css-style-checkboxes/

Answer (score 1):

Just set the checkbox's type to equal checkbox and add a border-radius as 100% in your CSS stylesheet, as well as specifying the height and width (which should be identical to each other in order to make a square as the base of your circle) , in order to make them totally rounded, as in  perfect circles. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

use radio buttons.
if you want multiple selection, you can set the same name for all the radio buttons and use different id's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudoclasses for the label, and visually hide the actual checkbox.

```
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 18px; height: 18px;
  border-radius: 9px; //this should be half of height and width
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #ffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  background: orange;
}
```